# how can i set focus of a rotator / carousel on my web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I set focus of a rotator / carousel on my web page

According to my code both the rotators get slided simultaneously  but I want only  that   rotator to slide which is focussed .

I added the tabindex attribute on the `"carousel_inner"` `div` and as well as I also  added   the tabindex on the `"#home_rotator"` `div` and then called the focus function but they are focused simultaneously in my webpage

My code is:

```
$("#carousel_inner").attr("tabindex",0).focus(function() {
    $(document).keydown(function(eventObject) {
        if(eventObject.which==37) {//left arrow
            $("#carousel_inner").focus();               
            $('#left_scroll').click();//emulates click on prev button 
        } else if(eventObject.which==39) {//right arrow
            $("#carousel_inner").focus();               
            $('#right_scroll').click();//emulates click on next button
        }   
    });
});
```

// Add keyboard navigation

```
$("#home_rotator").attr("tabindex",-1).focus(function() { 
    $(document).keydown(function(eventObject) {
        if(eventObject.which==37) {//left arrow
            $("#home_rotator").focus();             
            base.goBack();//emulates click on prev button 
        } else if(eventObject.which==39) {//right arrow
            $("#home_rotator").focus();             
            base.goForward();   //emulates click on next button 
        }           
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're binding events inside the focus function. Once an event is bound, it's bound. Unfocusing the element won't unbind the previous events, unless you explicitly tell it to by writing an `.unbind()` statement in a `.blur()` event.

But, you'd be better off binding the `.keydown()` event *once*, outside of the `focus()` event, then checking which element has focus and performing the required action.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) { 
    if ( document.activeElement.id === 'carousel_inner' ) {
        if ( e.which === 37 ) {
            // event for left key on carousel_inner
        }
        else if ( e.which === 39 ) {
            // event for right key on carousel_inner
        }
    }
    else if ( document.activeElement.id === 'home_rotator' ) {
        if ( e.which === 37 ) {
            // event for left key on home_rotator
        }
        else if ( e.which === 39 ) {
            // event for right key on home_rotator
        }
    }
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9ErRF/